# Can I avoid Captcha dialog when posting picture using Feed Dialog in iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, dialog, captcha, feed, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using the dialogs in Facebook iOS SDK to allow users's of our app to share a link on their news feed (SDK downloaded today to ensure I have latest version).  This was working last week and began behaving differently last Friday after an outage of the API service and a capture dialog is now appearing before the user can post. But the captcha image doesn't load and it says Unknown Error in the top right corner of the captcha dialog which is ugly and seems incorrect.

Has the Facebook API changed recently to now require captcha when posting picture or link? If I remove either picture or link from the params then the post dialog loads fine. I've tried a variety of different urls for my picture or link value and nothing seems to work except removing that param completely which I don't want to do. Can I post a picture or link  without the captcha step?

This is my code.

```
- (void)publishStream:(NSString *)postName caption:(NSString *)caption
{ 
  SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];
  NSDictionary* actionLinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary
                                                         dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                         @"Company Website",
                                                         @"name", 
                                                         @"http://mycompanysiteurl.com", 
                                                         @"link", 
                                                         nil], nil];

  NSString *actionLinksStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:actionLinks];

  NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 kAppId, @"app_id",
                                 @"http://mypictureurl.png", @"picture",
                                 postName, @"name",
                                 caption, @"caption",
                                 actionLinksStr, @"actions",
                                 nil];

  [_facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
}
```

I've tried various combinations of permissions when authorizing too with no luck (publish_stream, read_stream, publish_actions, photo_upload).

Not sure if I'm missing something obvious by I've been trying to fix this for days and have not found a solution other than removing the picture or link which is not an option for me due to requirements.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: UPDATE: 
I feel like a dope but I've answered my own question just now after a week of banging my head against a wall on this issue.

The problem was the value for the url of the @"picture" (or @"link") in the params. I changed this to a short bit.ly url and it now works but when it was a goo.gl short url it was broken as were a few other url options that I had tried. So the Facebook dialog api seems to be a bit fussy about what the url values are but the bit.ly urls seem to be ok...for now (* hoping FB doesn't break this in future API updates *).

Comment: Then please answer your own post and accept it. Avoids people coming to your questions thinking its not yet answered/solved.